# Google Maps Infowindow Renders different if content is passed by node or by string

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm a bit confused. I'm trying to load the content of a Google Maps (api v.3) infoWindow as a node. If I do so and the content is large, the expected vertical scroll-bar doesn't show and the content overflows the infowindow, which is very confusing for the user.

However, if I get exactly the same node and pass its html string representation to the InfoWindow it renders with the vertical scroll-bar.

I created a jsfiddle to ilustrate it:  http://jsfiddle.net/vEBUv/5/

Is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks for any suggestion

p.s.: I need to pass the content as a Node since I want to keep reference to the DOM elements

Code in jsFiddle:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
var mapNode = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas_node'), mapOptions);

var contentNode = $('#infoWindowContent')[0];
var contentString = $('#infoWindowContent').parent().html();

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var infowindowNode = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentNode
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatlng,
     map: map,
     title: 'Test Content as String'
});

var markerNode = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: mapNode,
    title: 'Test Content as Node'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerNode, 'click', function() {
    infowindowNode.open(mapNode,markerNode);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `overflow`-style of the parentNode of the content-node to `auto` when the `domready`-event of the infoWindow fires:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindowNode,'domready',function(){
  this.getContent().parentNode.style.overflow='auto';
});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7HdKt/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7HdKt/)

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle, I had already tested every combination of styles on the node itself but didn't tyied with its parent. Now it works as expected!